# Definition of Dual-Pairing

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dual-spaces

> Let $V$ be an $\mathbb{K}$-Vectorspace with basis $B :=(b_i)_{i \in
>  I}$ and $B^* = (b_i^*)_{i \in I}$ corresponding dual basis. Let $\Phi:
>  V \rightarrow V^*$ the isomorphism defined as $\Phi(v_i) = v_i^*$.
>
> The map:
>
> $$ \pi: V \times V^* \rightarrow \mathbb{K}, \,\,\,\,\,\,(v, \,f)
>  \mapsto f(v) $$
>
> is called the dual pairing of $V$. Let $$ \gamma_B: V \times V
>  \rightarrow \mathbb{K}, \,\,\,\,\,\,(v, \,w) \mapsto \pi(v, w^*) $$
>
> Show that $\gamma_B$ is a perfect, symmetrical bilinear form.  What is
>   $\gamma_B$ in the case of $V := \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B := (e_1, \dots,
>  e_n)$?

I was able to show that $\gamma_B$ is a perfect, symmetric bilinear form. But I don't quite understand what is meant by

> What is $\gamma_B$ in the case of $V := \mathbb{R}^n$ and $B := (e_1, \dots,
>  e_n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us consider $v,w \in V$, and let us compute $\gamma_B(v,w)$ step by step.

$\gamma_B(v,w) = \pi(v,w^*) = w^*(v).$

But recall that $w^*$ was defined in the following way : the isomorphism sends $b_i$ to $b_i^*$ (the linear form which sends $b_i$ to $1$ and the other $b_j$ to $0$)

So let us write $v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_ib_i$ and $w = \sum_{i=1}^n w_ib_i$ the decomposition of $v,w$ in the basis $B$. You then have $w^* = \sum_{i=1}^n w_ib_i^*$ so that

$\gamma_B(v,w) = \sum_{i=1}^n w_ib_i^*(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n w_iv_i = (v|w)$

where $( \cdot |\cdot)$ is just the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ : which was the special thing to notice in this case.

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you for your answer.